# Running upstart jobs as unprivileged users

Tags: ubuntu, setuid, upstart

What's the canonical way to have an upstart job change its userid and run the script as an unprivileged user?

Obviously one can use `su` or `sudo`, but this seems hacky (and can generate needless log lines).

Answer (score 110):

With upstart v1.4, [setuid](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#setuid) and [setgid](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#setgid) are supported natively in config file.

Comment: See the cookbook for specifics on this: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-job-as-a-different-user

Comment: In other words, it's supported in Precise (12.04) and newer.

Comment: In other words, is not supported in centos 6

Comment: Best answer if you have Upstart >= 1.4. You should bookmark the 'su' solution though as it can be handy when you need it.

Comment: For the record, `initctl --version` to find your current version of upstart.

Comment: Annoyingly, the Amazon Linux distro on AWS uses RHEL 6's upstart version (0.6.5 !!!!) so anyone using that will have to use the 'su' solution.

Comment: As an example, add the following line to your upstart script:
    `setuid www-data`

Answer (score 88):

Asking on the #upstart channel on freenode, the official take on the matter is:

> A future release of Upstart will have
>   native support for that, but for now,
>   you can use something like:
>
> ```
> exec su -s /bin/sh -c 'exec "$0" "$@"' username -- /path/to/command [parameters...]
> ```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked on Amazon Linue EC2 (I tried all variations of sudo and su, including --session-command, -c, ad nauseum); none of them allowed the process to be stopped once started; thanks so much for this.

Comment: That's some fancy shell magic, +1.

Comment: This didn't work for me on CentOS 6 (Upstart 0.6.5).  There are a series of forks (4 deep I think) initiated by `su` that means that `expect fork` and even `expect daemon` don't catch the final PID.

Comment: I used this on Amazon Linux (Upstart 0.6.5) to boot up a Jenkins process (which does not daemonize itself, thankfully) and it worked! I had to change it a little to redirect standard output to a log file and set some environment variables, but it worked! My version looks like: `exec su -s /bin/sh -c 'HOME=/foo/bar exec "$0" "$@" &>/var/log/foobar.log' username -- /path/to/command [parameters...]`

Comment: For CentOS 6, check out hxysayhi's answer below. It resolves the issue Mark Lakata identified

Answer (score 17):

How about using start-stop-daemon?

```
exec start-stop-daemon --start --chuid daemonuser --exec /bin/server_cmd
```

From [Upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/):

> The recommended method for Debian and Ubuntu systems is to use the helper utility `start-stop-daemon`. […] `start-stop-daemon` does not impose PAM ("Pluggable Authentication Module") limits to the process it starts.

Note: `start-stop-daemon` not supported in RHEL.

Comment: You can also use the group, if you need it. With --chuid daemonuser:daemongroup

Answer (score 13):

There are several ways to do it, all with slightly different semantics, particularly relating to group membership:

- `setuidgid` will put you in the group you specify.

  - The original daemontools' `setuidgid` will put you *only* in that group, so you won't be able to access files belonging to other groups you're a member of.
  - The [`setuidgid` from daemontools-encore](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/setuidgid.8.html) and the [`setuidgid` from the nosh toolset](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/setuidgid.html) both have an `-s` (a.k.a. `--supplementary`) option which will put you in that group, and also put you in all of the *supplementary groups* for the user that you specify.
- Using `newgrp` once you've become the less privileged user will add a single group to your groupset, but also creates a new subshell, making it tricky to use inside scripts.
- `start-stop-daemon` preserves your group membership, and does a whole lot more than just setuid/setgid.
- `chpst -u username:group1:group2:group3... commandname` will let you specify exactly what group memberships to adopt, but (in *Ubuntu*) it only comes with the `runit` package, which is an alternative to `upstart`.
- `su -c commandname username` picks up all of username's group memberships, as does `sudo -u username commandname`, so they're probably the route to least astonishment.

Answer (score 8):

Use `setuidgid` from the package `daemontools`.

Documentation here: http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/setuidgid.html

Comment: daemontools isn't a prerequisite of upstart, so this doesn't seem like the 'canonical' answer

Comment: Further, daemontools is in universe (ubuntu 10.04), and upstart is in main.

Answer (score 4):

On an Ubuntu 10.10 instance on Amazon EC2, I had better luck with the `start-stop-daemon` command.

I also struggled with some of the other upstart *stanzas*.  I am calling a python application with a specific `virtualenv` and some parameters to my executed program.

The following is what worked for me.

```
script
  export PYTHONPATH=.:/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:/home/ubuntu/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
  exec start-stop-daemon --start  --chuid ubuntu --exec /home/ubuntu/python_envs/MyProj/bin/python /home/ubuntu/www/MyProj/MyProj.py -- --config-file-dir=/home/ubuntu/www/MyProj/config/ >> /home/ubuntu/startup.log 2>&1 &
end script
```

The `PYTHONPATH` is to get some packages installed from source into the *PYTHON* module path when this upstart job runs.  I had to do everything in absolute paths because the `chdir` stanza didn't seem to do work.

Comment: I have also had problems with *env* variables used with *exec start-stop-daemon*.

Answer (score 3):

I was using CentOS 6, and I could not get the recommended hack (for Upstart 0.6.5) to work for me, nor the 'su' trick because the number of forks involved (4 I think) was not tracked by 'expect fork' or 'expect daemon'.

I eventually just did

```
chown user:group executable
chmod +s executable
```

(ie set the setuid bit and change the ownership).

It may not be the safest method, but for an internal R&D project, it didn't matter in our case.

Comment: If you were to do a `chmod 1700` or at least a `chmod u+sx,go-x` in there instead of just `+s`, it'd qualify as "secure enough." :)

Answer (score 2):

In CentOS 6, upstart 0.6.5, the following is what worked for me.

```
script

    exec su user_name << EOF
        exec /path/to/command [parameters...]
EOF

end script
```

or :

```
script

    exec su user_name << EOF
       ..... what you want to do ....
EOF

end script
```

When use

```
exec su -s /bin/sh -c 'exec "$0" "$@"' username -- /path/to/command [parameters...]
```

the job process can't be stopped by `initclt stop` .
I think the reason is:

```
1. the job forked and the main process is not tracked.
2. the main process changed its process group,because of `su -c`
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a third possibility depending on what you are trying to accomplish.  You may be able to **loosen the access controls on the files/devices in question**.  This can allow an unprivileged user to mount or access items that they normally wouldn't be allowed to.  Just be sure you aren't giving away the keys to the kingdom in the process.

You can also **change the timeout of the sudo password cache**.  But I don't recommend it unless your machine is physically secure (i.e., you believe that it's unlikely that a passer-by would attempt to gain sudo access).

There's a good reason that there are very few ways to perform privileged actions and that they perform <strike>needless</strike> *necessary* logging.  Loose restrictions would be a security hazard for your system, and a lack of logging would mean there's no way to know what happened when you've been compromised.

If the *size* of your log files is a concern then something is probably wrong.  Sudo generates only one line per use under normal conditions.